# Forçar exibição de menu na action bar de celulares com botão de menu

Tags: android

Em celulares tipo os da Samsung que tem o botão de menu, o menu da action bar no android não é exibido, gostaria de saber se tem como forçar a exibição dele?

Meu menu.xml está assim:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:showAsAction="always"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_criar_conta"
    android:title="@string/action_criar_conta"
  />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_entrar"
    android:title="@string/action_entrar"

    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_anuncie"
    android:title="@string/action_anunciar"

    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponho que deve estar a usar a *v7 appcompat library* e `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` como *Theme* da aplicação.

O atributo `showAsAction`, quando usado com a *library*, tem de ser precedido do nome da app.
Vejo que está a colocar esse atributo na declaração do *namespace* da aplicação, confesso que não sei qual é o propósito.

A forma que eu uso para declarar o menu é a descrita na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_criar_conta"
        android:title="@string/action_criar_conta"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_entrar"
        android:title="@string/action_entrar"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_anuncie"
        android:title="@string/action_anunciar"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Além disso o menu deve ser construído no método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

**Nota:** Na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) também se pode ler que não é recomendado a utilização de `"always"` porque pode provocar "problemas" de *layout* em dispositivos de "tela estreita". Em sua substituição é melhor usar `"ifRoom"` ou `"ifRoom|withText"`

Comment: E em todos dispositivos aparece o menu? Tive problemas com dispositivos tipo o galaxy y s5360b

Comment: Os problemas que teve foi com o seu código ou com o meu? No *galaxy y* não sei mas no *galaxy Gio GT S5660* funciona.

Comment: Com o meu código, vou testar o seu.